# Need slide animation on back press

Tags: android, slide

Just want to perform slide animation on back press..Here is my code:

```
    txtBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_out, R.anim.right_in);
        onBackPressed();
        }
    });
```

I don't want to use intent for a reason.

Comment: I dont have the intention of answering this question for a reason

Comment: it's not entirely clear what you are trying to do. is the user pushing the back button on the device, or tapping a widget in your user interface? are you calling `finish()` or `startActivity()` or some such in response? the fragment you posted seems nonsensical.

Comment: just want to finish this activity..in place of backpress.. you may call finish as well

Comment: And what is your question? That code should be right (if the animations you're calling are well defined, and you don't have anything weird overriding the onBackPressed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
finish();
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_out, R.anim.right_in);
```

`overridePendingTransition()` must be called *after* `finish()`.